# AWS API gateway issue with POSTMAN

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, http-post, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I'm new to API gateway. So i created a basic API with basic route and lambda integration. It is auto-deploy enabled.

so API invoke URL looks like -
https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/

I have not added any authorizers to it. I have added * in all fields of CORS
[image]

HTTP method i am trying to hit from POSTMAN is POST

So, when i'm using the given invoke URL which has **https** - https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ the response i'm getting is invalid http method. So I tried using http for the endpoint, then the console is showing

*POST http://xxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 18.xxx.xxx.126:80*

Looking at the error, I am able to understand that the API gateway is refusing the connection but what am I missing? Can anyone help me out please

Comment: You have to always POST to a stage within the API, e.g. https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/default .

Comment: I have created a stage "test" and i have tried POSTing it to https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/test/ and its still giving me the same issue